# Open Modal Dialog from Modal Dialog using Selenium Web Driver Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog

I am using Selenium Web Driver to test a application and I have a problem.
The problem is, I have a Modal Dialog and a have to open another Modal Dialog, but When I call the second Modal Dialog, selenium open the Second in the same windows.
Following the code:

public class NewContract {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    ................
    Using this code to not stop the Selenium Web Driver
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.showModalDialog = window.open;"); 

    //clicking on the next steps will open the new contract pop-up window
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='bs-example-navbar")).click();

    // Switch to new window opened
    for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    } 

    // New Contract Windows 
    //Switch to Iframe
    driver.switchTo().frame("compContentFrame");  

    ..............
    Using this code to not stop the Selenium Web Driver
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.showModalDialog = window.open;"); 

    //Click Select Template
    driver.findElement(By.id("SelectTemplateButton:img")).click();

    }
```

}

My question is: How I do to OPEN 2 Modal Dialogs with selenium web driver?
[First Modal Opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxh4f.jpg)
[Second overwrites the first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvSCo.jpg)

Comment: I don't entirely understand your question.The screenshots don't really give us any insight on what you're trying to accomplish. Both the dialogs are opened on your screen. What's the issue ? Do you mean that the second dialog overwrites the first dialog when the driver attempts to open it? Can you attach a screenshot of when they're opened in the same window?

Comment: you should just have locators for the second modal?  it shouldn't matter.  Please provide example html.

Comment: Henry Lin, user2272115

Do you mean that the second dialog overwrites the first dialog when the driver attempts to open it? Yes, when the script calls the second modal, the second modal overwrites the first. I need stay with first and second modal open.

Picture_Modal1 = Selenium opens the first Modal Dialog
Picture_Modal2 = Selenium overwrites the first Modal Dialog